# Resetting password during multiple login through parse.com

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, backend

I am using parse framework for both Android and iOS for my app. But I have q question that while using resetting password functionality of user, what will happen if sane user is logged in two devices at the same time and he requests to reset the password from one device. So what will happen to another login, do we ourselves need to put some constraint on it or parse will provide something useful.